# Issues in md-select using nested JSON - AngularJs 1.X.X

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, angular-material, md-select

I having a two drop downs "Department" and "Designation". Initially I loaded the Department and based on Department selection, the Designation will auto populate. Kindly have a look into the JSON object

```
{
   "Status":true,
   "Message":"",
   "Result":[
      {
         "DepartmentId":1,
         "Name":"Bala",
         "Designation":[
            {
               "DesignationId":1,
               "DepartmentId":1,
               "Name":"Software Engg"
            },
            {
               "DesignationId":3,
               "DepartmentId":1,
               "Name":"Sr. Human Resouce"
            },
            {
               "DesignationId":2,
               "DepartmentId":1,
               "Name":"Sr. Software Engg"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "DepartmentId":2,
         "Name":"Dev",
         "Designation":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "DepartmentId":3,
         "Name":"HR Team",
         "Designation":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "DepartmentId":4,
         "Name":"Sales",
         "Designation":[
            {
               "DesignationId":4,
               "DepartmentId":4,
               "Name":"Sr. Sales Manager"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The final Version of HTML is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Department:</p>
<md-select ng-model="Select.department" tabindex="9">
        <md-option ng-repeat="key in loadUpData.Department" value="{{key}}">{{key.Name}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
      <br/>
<p>Designation:</p>
<md-select ng-model="Select.department" tabindex="9">
        <md-option ng-repeat="key in Select.department.Designation" value="{{key}}">{{key.Name}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope){

       $scope.loadUpData = {
                    Department: 
angular.fromJson("{" +
"   \"Status\":true," +
"   \"Message\":\"\"," +
"   \"Result\":[" +
"      {" +
"         \"DepartmentId\":1," +
"         \"Name\":\"Bala\"," +
"         \"Designation\":[" +
"            {" +
"               \"DesignationId\":1," +
"               \"DepartmentId\":1," +
"               \"Name\":\"Software Engg\"" +
"            }," +
"            {" +
"               \"DesignationId\":3," +
"               \"DepartmentId\":1," +
"               \"Name\":\"Sr. Human Resouce\"" +
"            }," +
"            {" +
"               \"DesignationId\":2," +
"               \"DepartmentId\":1," +
"               \"Name\":\"Sr. Software Engg\"" +
"            }" +
"         ]" +
"      }," +
"      {" +
"         \"DepartmentId\":2," +
"         \"Name\":\"Dev\"," +
"         \"Designation\":[" +
"         ]" +
"      }," +
"      {" +
"         \"DepartmentId\":3," +
"         \"Name\":\"HR Team\"," +
"         \"Designation\":[" +
"         ]" +
"      }," +
"      {" +
"         \"DepartmentId\":4," +
"         \"Name\":\"Sales\"," +
"         \"Designation\":[" +
"            {" +
"               \"DesignationId\":4," +
"               \"DepartmentId\":4," +
"               \"Name\":\"Sr. Sales Manager\"" +
"            }" +
"         ]" +
"      }" +
"   ]" +
"}").Result
                };

       $scope.Select = {
                    Department: {},
                    Designation: {}
                };

$scope.$watchCollection('Select.department', function (newData, oldDaata) {
    if ((newData != undefined) && (newData != null)) {
        console.log($scope.loadUpData.Department);
    }
});

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first drop-down works perfectly but I can't able to populate the second drop-down. Kindly assist me.

Comment: try to use ng-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ng-change` function to get changes from first `md-select`, find the updated code.

Working [**jsfiddel**](https://jsfiddle.net/mvh342da/)

Html

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Department:</p>
  <md-select ng-model="select.Department" tabindex="9" ng-change="onChange(select.Department)">
    <md-option ng-repeat="key in loadUpData.Department" value="{{key}}">{{key.Name}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
  <br/>
  <p>Designation:</p>
  <md-select ng-model="select.Designation" tabindex="9">
    <md-option ng-repeat="key in designationData" value="{{key}}">{{key.Name}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.loadUpData = {
    Department: angular.fromJson("{" +
      "   \"Status\":true," +
      "   \"Message\":\"\"," +
      "   \"Result\":[" +
      "      {" +
      "         \"DepartmentId\":1," +
      "         \"Name\":\"Bala\"," +
      "         \"Designation\":[" +
      "            {" +
      "               \"DesignationId\":1," +
      "               \"DepartmentId\":1," +
      "               \"Name\":\"Software Engg\"" +
      "            }," +
      "            {" +
      "               \"DesignationId\":3," +
      "               \"DepartmentId\":1," +
      "               \"Name\":\"Sr. Human Resouce\"" +
      "            }," +
      "            {" +
      "               \"DesignationId\":2," +
      "               \"DepartmentId\":1," +
      "               \"Name\":\"Sr. Software Engg\"" +
      "            }" +
      "         ]" +
      "      }," +
      "      {" +
      "         \"DepartmentId\":2," +
      "         \"Name\":\"Dev\"," +
      "         \"Designation\":[" +
      "         ]" +
      "      }," +
      "      {" +
      "         \"DepartmentId\":3," +
      "         \"Name\":\"HR Team\"," +
      "         \"Designation\":[" +
      "         ]" +
      "      }," +
      "      {" +
      "         \"DepartmentId\":4," +
      "         \"Name\":\"Sales\"," +
      "         \"Designation\":[" +
      "            {" +
      "               \"DesignationId\":4," +
      "               \"DepartmentId\":4," +
      "               \"Name\":\"Sr. Sales Manager\"" +
      "            }" +
      "         ]" +
      "      }" +
      "   ]" +
      "}").Result
  };

  $scope.Select = {
    Department: {},
    Designation: {}
  };

  $scope.onChange = function(selected) {
      var Designation = JSON.parse(selected).Designation;
      console.log(Designation);
      $scope.designationData = Designation;
  };

});
```

Comment: How to get the respective `DepartmentId` and `DesignationId` from `$scope.select.Department` and `$scope.select.Designation` respectively.